# How to submit data to SQL Server database using infopath without code

Tags: infopath

Can someone tell me how do I update/modify SQL Server database from using info path form with code?

Currently I'm using InfoPath to receive data from SQL database.

Thank you

Detailed help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a new form using the Database template or are you connecting to the DB after the fact from a list you wanted to add the SQL db connection to? The easiest route is just to Create a new IP form using the Database template under the Advanced templates as it creates the fields and controls to enter and edit the SQL data you want to work with. If not then you need to run a SQL CREATE statement.

Answer (score -2):

I use infopath to create a Sharepoint list and then Visual Studio SSIS package to transfer the sharepoint list data to a SQL database table, using a schedule stored procedure.

Comment: Can you please share the step by step process and sharepoint list to SQL database code ?
i will be very thankful